# filtering out zero total from nested result in graphql query

Tags: graphql

I have the following query that can be run against the github graphql API

```
query userRepositories($cursor: String, $q: String!, $githubId: String!) {
  search(query: $q, type: REPOSITORY, first: 100, after: $cursor) {
    repositoryCount
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      startCursor
    }
    nodes {
      ... on Repository {
        id
        name
        description
        isArchived
        isPrivate
        nameWithOwner
        url
        defaultBranchRef {
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              history(first: 10, author: {id: $githubId}) {
                totalCount
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns results like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "repositoryCount": 103,
      "pageInfo": {
        "endCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOjEwMA==",
        "startCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOjE="
      },
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk2MTg1OTczOA==",
          "name": "microstates",
          "nameWithOwner": "thefrontside/microstates",
          "url": "https://github.com/thefrontside/microstates",
          "defaultBranchRef": {
            "target": {
              "history": {
                "totalCount": 0
              }
            }
          },        
         {
          "id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxNTU5MTUyODc=",
          "name": "effection",
          "nameWithOwner": "thefrontside/effection",
          "url": "https://github.com/thefrontside/effection",
          "defaultBranchRef": {
            "target": {
              "history": {
                "totalCount": 16
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

I am only interested in the nodes array that has a `defaultBranchRef.target.history.totalCount` that is greater than 0.

So I am not interested in element 0 of the `nodes` array but I am of element 1.

Can I filter this in graphql or do I have to do that in code outside of the query?

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL can't filter an array so if the API support filter base on `totalCount` you can pass this filter otherwise you have to filter in your code. In JS it's very easy:

```js
const filtered = {
  ...data,
  search: {
    ...data.search,
    nodes: data.search.nodes.filter(node => node.defaultBranchRef.target.history.totalCount > 0),
  }
};
```